# Levitation inside a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, levitation, inductance

Is it possible to levitate something inside a solenoid? If yes, is it possible in any direction (horizontal, vertical)? Also, is it possible when an object is traveling through?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the direction of magnetic field in a solenoid? What happens if the current in the wire is increased? What's the force of gravity on a mass? What is the force of magnetic field? What you should do to increase the magnetic force so as to balance the weight of the mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to levitate something inside a solenoid

Why not? One can levitate a small frog whose mass is less.The skin of most animals are diamagnetic in nature so it repels the external field.One can adjust the mass of the diamagnetic material such that it is repelled by an equal amount of force which increases till the centre of the non ideal solenoid.

> Is it possible in any direction (horizontal and vertical)?

If we consider the situation of a non ideal solenoid producing magnetic field inside it and the frog of small mass, then force due to magnetic field will be along the axis of an ideal solenoid.This force needs to be opposite and equal to the weight of the frog to make it levitate.
So conclusively the axis of the solenoid must be parallel to the direction of force produced by weight of the object to make it levitate on the the magnetic field if solenoid,**also the direction of magnetic field should be opposite to the direction of weight**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is done regularly with [levitation induction heating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VydPQuLyEns) and [here](http://www.inductionheatertutorial.com/)